# How to updated 3D Touch Quick Actions localized Subtitle?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, 3dtouch

I am adding all my 3D Touch actions in my app delegate but how can I update the subtitle of one of the actions throughout my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationShortcutItem_class/) from Apple. The first code sample gives you what you need to modify an existing quick action with a new `localizedTitle`.

Here's the Objective-C code from the Apple example. In summary, you create a `UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem` with a mutable copy of the shortcut item you want to modify. Change the title and then replace the previous shortcut with the new one.

```
NSArray <UIApplicationShortcutItem *> *existingShortcutItems = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] shortcutItems];
UIApplicationShortcutItem *anExistingShortcutItem = [existingShortcutItems objectAtIndex: anIndex];
NSMutableArray <UIApplicationShortcutItem *> *updatedShortcutItems = [existingShortcutItems mutableCopy];
UIMutableApplicationShortcutItem *aMutableShortcutItem = [anExistingShortcutItem mutableCopy];
[aMutableShortcutItem setLocalizedTitle: @“New Title”];
[updatedShortcutItems replaceObjectAtIndex: anIndex withObject: aMutableShortcutItem];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setShortcutItems: updatedShortcutItems];
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12131735)

Comment: @frasertweedale I copied the Apple sample code with some explanatory text.